# How to trigger a javascript function using vbscript?

Tags: javascript, function, vbscript

I am trying to click a Print button using vbscript. However, it doesn't actually fire the appropriate events. So now I think I need to figure out a way to call the function itself.

Here is the button code:

```
<input name="ucDetailsAJ1670783$btnPrint" tabindex="-1" class="rbDecorated rbPrimary" id="ucDetailsAJ1670783_btnPrint_input" style="width: 100%; padding-right: 4px; padding-left: 0px;" type="submit" value="Print">

<input name="ucDetailsAJ1670783_btnPrint_ClientState" id="ucDetailsAJ1670783_btnPrint_ClientState" type="hidden" value='{"text":"Print","value":"","checked":false,"target":"","navigateUrl":"","commandName":"","commandArgument":"","autoPostBack":false,"selectedToggleStateIndex":0,"validationGroup":null,"readOnly":false,"primary":false,"enabled":true}' autocomplete="off">
```

Here is the print function code:

```
function btnPrint_OnClientClicking(sender, args)
{

        doPrint();


    return false;
}

function openPopup()
{
    var url = document.location.origin + '/Customized/CustomizedControls/DEAModules/Search/PrintDetails.aspx?RelId=605598&Key=29_117_8_167_19_163_12_121_129_12_163_128_60_154_31_198_70_205_6_230_173_133_82_216_52_56_178_209_108_67_255_205';
        var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
        if (win) win.focus();
}

function doPrint()
{
        var divButtons = document.getElementById('ucDetailsAJ1670783_divButtons');  
        if (divButtons) { divButtons.style.display = 'none'; }

        setTimeout("window.print();", 300);

}
```

Here is my code & the error messages I receive(using vbscript to call a javascript function) I know I am missing something:

> Null error message

```
objIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "doPrint();", "javascript"
```

> Expected statement

```
objIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "doPrint();", "jscript"
```

> Unterminated string constant

```
objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "btnPrint_OnClientClicking(sender, args);", "javascript"
```

> Expected statement

```
objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "btnPrint_OnClientClicking();", "javascript"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have fallen foul of changes in Internet Explorer 11

> <sup>From [MSHTML Reference - execScript method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa741364(v%3Dvs.85))</sup>
>
> **[IHTMLWindow2::execScript** is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use [eval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12k71sw7). For info, see [Compatibility changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bg182625).]